# Import tensorflow in jupyter notebook fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, environment-variables, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When updating `tensorflow` to version 1.4, `cudnn` to version 6 and setting up SSL encryption and a password on my jupyter notebook server I constantly got the following error in notebooks:

```
ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Importing tensorflow inside `python3 -i` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that the necessary environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set when testing it with `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on the host but `print(os.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'))` in notebooks results in a `KeyError`.

Setting the variable in `.bashrc` and `.profile` didn't change anything.

The solution was to run `jupyter notebook` with a modified environment with `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH jupyter notebook`.